# Using Compiled Model for DbContext - Bad Sql Connection

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a DbContext that I want to spin up to handle a series of tables with identical properties.  Since OnModelCreating only gets fired once, I need to compile the model manually and pass it into the constructor in order for it to respect the changes in table name.

In my construction path, I do something similar to this:

```
var modelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder();
var cs = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MyConnectionString");
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(cs.ConnectionString)) {

  // This sets up the ToTable/HasKey/etc information
  ConfigureSpecificModelInformation(modelBuilder);
  var model = modelBuilder.Build(connection).Compile();

  // DbContext with an IDbSet<T> Entities
  Context = new MyDbContext(model);

  // This will throw a SqlException (inside of an EntityException)
  Context.Entities.ToList();
}
```

The exception is:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot open database "Namespace.Name.ForThisContext.MyDbContext" requested by the login
```

The connection I pass in is valid and is used in other more conventional spots.  The model seems to use the connection to build up, but once it gets into the context, it may be using some unicorn magic to infer an incorrect database based on the context name.

It's been difficult for me to find information about this and since MS has removed the ability for us to turn off model caching, I'm in need of a way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [this overload for a DbContext's ctor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696127%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). That allows you to pass also the connection you're using. I.e:

```
var modelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder();
var cs = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MyConnectionString");
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(cs.ConnectionString)) {

  // This sets up the ToTable/HasKey/etc information
  ConfigureSpecificModelInformation(modelBuilder);
  var model = modelBuilder.Build(connection).Compile();

  // DbContext with an IDbSet<T> Entities
  Context = new MyDbContext(connection, model, false);

  // This will throw a SqlException (inside of an EntityException)
  Context.Entities.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer was correct - forest for the trees on this one.